# Global.asax can't find code-behind class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-2

I keep getting this error when I try to run a web app that I have inherited. It was written in 2010 for C# 3.5 and uses Mvc 2. I have installed the necessary libraries however I get this error.

> Error 1   Could not load type
>   'AdminConsole.MvcApplication'.    C:\path\to\my\app\Global.asax   1

Global.asax.cs looks like this:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace AdminConsole
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Entitlement", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
```

And Global.asax looks like this: `<%@ Application Inherits="AdminConsole.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>`

Comment: Are you sure MVC is installed on the target server and that the DLLs have built?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `Codebehind="Global.asax.cs"` to the `Markup` file (Global.asax):

**From:**

```
<%@ Application Inherits="AdminConsole.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

**To:**

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs"
                Inherits="AdminConsole.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

Comment: This and moving Global.asax.cs to the App_Data folder, however does fix the error.

Comment: Moving the Global.asax.cs to the App_Code folder works of course too. This really helped thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Verify that the project is configured to place your DLLs into the `/bin` folder and not in `/bin/x86/Debug/` (or similar).

Comment: Can't this be configured somehow to work with a Debug or Release Folder?

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I had accidentally created a web *site* instead of a web *application*. Once I recreated the project it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

As written by @FMM

> Verify that the project is configured to place your DLLs into the /bin
> folder and not in /bin/x86/Debug/ (or similar).

I could check, and resolve my issue, changing the configuration manager. Then, changing the platform, from "x86" to "Any CPU".

1 - configuration manager:

[image: 1 - configuration manager]

2 - x86 to Any CPU:

[image: 2 - x86 to Any CPU]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31983649)